# Mantain page state when coming pressing back button in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

Here is my situation:

I have a page with one container which shows all the users, and with another container which will show the users if I have applied any filters.
So, by default I show all the users in the container with id all_users, and if I apply any filters, I hide that container and I do an AJAX call with the ids of my filters and put the contents of the results in a container with id .filtered_users.

When I click on a user though, I go to his page, but when I click the back button I always get all users. I don't get the users that were filtered when I click to that particular user.

How do you do it to mantain the state between those two pages? So that when I click the back button I know where I came from when I clicked into the user.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just track the state through the address-bar in browser, so that you have different addresses for all_users and filtered_users, and thus return to the right one when going back.

It can be manipulated through the history object. See, for example, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history